# Shrinking subnets in a an AWS VPC

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, subnet

Our primary VPC is configured with four subnets. As you can see below, the four
subnets span all of the available ip-addresses within the "10.50.?.?" block.
Since all of the available addresses are encompassed within that 10.50 prefix,
we are unable to create additional subnets.

We would like to create additional subnets in the 10.50.?.? block in (new)
different availability zones because they include (for example) newer instance
types. We have a similar issue in other regions.

All of the available ipv4 addresses are not actually in use. However, the web
UI will not allow us to "shrink" the existing subets. The way this scenario
appears to us, we would have to stop all of our instances to free up the
subnets, and remove them before creating new, smaller subnets.

```
fr-usx-lan-a subnet-a42932c1 vpc-1d0f1b78 10.50.0.0   /18 us-west-2a
fr-usx-wan-a subnet-962932f3 vpc-1d0f1b78 10.50.128.0 /18 us-west-2a
fr-usx-wan-b subnet-357d286c vpc-1d0f1b78 10.50.192.0 /18 us-west-2c
fr-usx-lan-b subnet-1d7d2844 vpc-1d0f1b78 10.50.64.0  /18 us-west-2c
```

We would like to have access to these subnets as well (in the Oregon region):

```
2b, 2d
```

If it is unclear from the text above, we would like to keep using the 10.50.?.?
prefix for all instances running in that region. We would also like to avoid
having to stop and recreate instances that are currently in production.

---

Currently, I have to admit that I at a bit of a loss of how to proceed here. I'm thinking some kind of temporary VPC with a bridge between them would be viable. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't shrink your subnets. You could delete them all and start again, or you could create a new VPC and migrate resources over. I don't think you're going to be able to keep the instance running easily - hopefully someone comes up with an idea for you though. You might be best off setting up the new VPC, changing DNS to point to the new instances, then once the old ones are unused turn them off. With your IP restrictions it could be tricky - I'd need to know more to come up with a more detailed plan

Answer (score 1):

Implement IPv6. One /64 per subnet is effectively unlimited addresses. Use a /56 from AWS for 256 /64s.

Unfortunately, I don't have a v4 option, especially not with the restriction of keeping the same range and staying running.

Classic example of a v4 address plan appearing large, until it needs to be further subdivided into new nets. Don't underestimate work spent in counting hosts and defragmenting ranges.

Comment: The range is large enough. Issue is, it was configured too large and the four subnets spanned the whole /28 address space. Rookie mistake / short-term planning. IPv4 is not the issue here.

Comment: My point is with v6 the /56 you are given supports 256 subnets that will never need to be resized.  I don't have a v4 solution.

Answer (score 1):

It won't help you now because I've only just come across this, but for the exercise...

You have two subnets in each region, can you fit all your ec2 instances in one subnet per region?
That is move all ec2 instances in `10.50.0.0/18` (us-west-2a) to `10.50.128.0/18` (us-west-2a)
Then delete `10.50.0.0/18` and create the number of subnets you want, eg `10.50.0.0/20`, `10.50.16.0/20`, `10.50.32.0/20`, `10.50.48.0/20`
then move the ec2 instances back, and repeat for the other subnets.

Of course moving ec2 instances to different subnets may not be that trivial depending. And you'll have to stop them because you have to make an AMI then launch that in the new subnet. https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-ec2-instance/
Depends on your application though if you'll need downtime. If you have HA at the application layer you may be able to migrate without downtime.